# Wcf client call delay more 10 sec... in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, wcf, service, delay

i want with WCF Connected service in .Net core 3, currently  i've a  wcf method for create a pdf document...

the method works well locally, delay between 1500 - 2500 ms... but when i publish the app in IIS this method delay more 15000ms, that's too much and the user is scared, can this be optimized at the code level? or is it an IIS configuration?

```
private async Task<DocumentsService.invokeResponse> _createDoc(string strXml)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    var endpoint = new DocumentsService.wsDocumentsClient.EndpointConfiguration();
    var service = new DocumentsService.wsDocumentsClient(endpoint);
    var response = new DocumentsService.invokeResponse();

    var parameter = new DocumentsService.XML();
    parameter.document = strXml;

    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user"
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

    var scope = new OperationContextScope(service.InnerChannel);
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    response = await service.invokeAsync(parameter); //this delay

    timer.Stop();
    var time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds; //local host 1500 - 2500 ms... in IIS more 10.000 ms
    return response;
 }
```

Update: the method delay is response = await service.invokeAsync(parameter);

Comment: So which method is taking the 15 seconds? Also is this on repeated calls, or just the first time?

Comment: hi, the method delay is  response = await service.invokeAsync(parameter)
and its only one call, not many.

Comment: Sorry, i mean to say, is it only on the first call (that you test), if you call this _createDoc twice, is there still a 15 second delay? is it consistently 15 seconds every time you call it

Comment: The truth is that I have not done that test, 
what do you want to do with what you mention?


the test I have done is pressing the "generate" button several times from the frontend, and if it also takes more than 15 seconds

Comment: Its likely the that app pool isn't loaded, and that the delay is the app pool spinning up, if that`s the case you may be able to pre-load it, or takes other measures However we cant give you advice as your complaint at the moment is slow code and we haven't properly identified the problem .

Comment: Try to use IP address to connect, and see if any timing differences.

Comment: Can it create a PDF file properly? It might be something wrong with `read/write` permission. In other words, the application pool identity running the website might have no permission to write a PDF file. try to specify the LocalSystem account.
Besides, it is also possible that the application pool needs to load it when the website first creates a large file, which results in that the creation operation takes a long time.